# How to rig objects to rotate around their long axes?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I thought I could find a tutorial for this, but so far no joy. What I want to do is rig/constrain these solar panels so I can manually rotate them around their long axes regardless of the orientation of the larger spacecraft model. Rigging 101? Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks! Windows 10, Blender 3.0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One root parent bone establish the main rot of the whole objects. 4 child bones control the panels: if the bones are created in edit mode with their long axis lying on the panels long axis, animating their Y local coordinates will result in the rotation you need, regardless of the global rotation of the root bone.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Marty Fouts. I’ve got some homework. :)